What exactly is concatenated to array, as res is just the recursive function but not an array?
I'm trying to understand this code which uses recursion to retrieve all HTML elements of a given CSS class:
var getElementsByClassName = function(className, element = document.body) {
    var arr = [];
    if (element.classList && element.classList.contains(className)) {
        arr.push(element);
    }
    for (var i = 0; i < element.childNodes.length; i++) {
        var res = getElementsByClassName(className, element.childNodes[i]);
        arr = arr.concat(res);
    }
    return arr;
};

At first I thought I understood, assuming that arr concatenates the content of arr that gets initialized with a new element in each recursive call.
But then I found out that I'm wrong. Or, if I'm not wrong, then how does that even work?
As var res is holding the recursive call, but what's even more, its content is to be concatenated with arr? I'm lost...
Can we get rid of the var res and instead use
arr = arr.concat(getElementsByClassName(className, element.childNodes[i]))

How does this whole process work?

Do you understand how simpler recusive functions work, such as recursive factorial? If you understand that then you might have an easier time understanding how this works.

I'm just trying to get a better picture about what you don't understand. Because currently "As var res is holding the recursive call but whats even its content to be concatinated with arr" seems to hint that you're not aware of how the recursive call returns a value to the calling function. If you understand how simpler recursive functions work like the factorial one and how it builds up its result once it hits the "base case", then that will assist in understanding how this one works since it applies the same concepts.

Also: https://stackoverflow.com/conduct

Okey im really sorry man , so yeah i do understand how the recursive factorial works but im having a difficulty understanding this one , does the var res holds the return of the function which is arr that through each recursive call would either push 1 element into it or 0 , and then for each iteration the arr = arr.concat(res) means that arr is getting the return of res which is the content of arr , in each iteration ?

It's ok. So res is an array with zero or more elements in it that has all the children that have the target className. So the first if statement may push the current element if has the className, but then the following concat() call could return multiple elements (ie: all the children of the current element that have the className you're searching for). So after each recursive call to getElementsByClassName() is complete, the array returned is an accumulation of all elements below the current element that have the className you're searching for.

In the title you wrote:

... as res is just the recursive function but not an array

This seems to be the core of the misunderstanding. It is the array. If res were "just the recursive function", then you would need to assign a function (object), but here you call the function, and so then the function executes, returns something (an array in this case) and that is what the right hand side evaluates to -- not the function, but what its execution returns.
To illustrate with a simple function:
var x = Math.abs;

Here x is a function object. But if we call it...
var x = Math.abs(-3)

...then x has no trace of the function abs. It is just the value 3.
In your case the function returns an array with the only return statement it has: return arr. As arr is an array, we can trust the function to always return an array.

Can we get rid of the var res and instead use
arr = arr.concat(getElementsByClassName(className, element.childNodes[i]))


Yes, that practically has the same effect. Note that in both cases you execute the function getElementsByClassName and use the value it returns as argument for a call of concat.
